# Chrome extension to change WebGL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on an extension for Chrome that would alter my "Hash of WebGL fingerprint" as per https://panopticlick.eff.org/results?aat=1&dnt=111#fingerprintTable

I started off using the code provided in the following link
https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/, basically copying it in my concept.js file, which looks as follows:

```
const getParameter = WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter;
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function(parameter) {
  // UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL
  if (parameter === 37445) {
    return 'Intel Open Source Technology Center';
  }
  // UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL
  if (parameter === 37446) {
    return 'Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile ';
  }

  return getParameter(parameter);
};
```

My manifest json is fairly simple and is set to run at document_start, which it does. However, using the above stated extension there is no difference in my WebGL hash. I know that the code in the extension actually runs as I have tested it with a bunch of small javascript alerts.

I am completely at a loss and have worked on this problem for several hours to no avail, all help is greatly appreciatedj

EDIT: For completeness sake following is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "JavaScript Injection",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["injected-javascript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that changes like this will be detectable, for example with abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - [isolated code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world).
You can use this code, but it is not work perfectly. I'am still in search for better solution, because this snippet depends on page load time. If you hit Shift + Ctrl + C it will works well, but simple Ctrl + C don't, becase page loads faster than interval starts.

```js
const getParameter = WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter;
const a = setInterval(() => {
  if (!document.body) {
    return
  }
  clearInterval(a);
  var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
  script_tag.type = 'text/javascript';
  script_tag.text = 'WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function(parameter) {' +
    'if (parameter === 37445) { return "Intel Open Source Technology Center"; };' + 
    'if (parameter === 37446) { return "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile "; }; return getParameter(parameter);' +
  '}';
  document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
}, 1);
```

Read more about this issue [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/use-a-content-script-to-access-the-page-context-variables-and-functions)